# How can I test web performance for PHP website on localhost?

Tags: php, performance, developer-tools

I'm building a web application using PHP, I'm about to finish it, but I decided to test the load time using the Chrome developer tools (network-tab), and I realized that there are some stylesheets and images that take more time than my PHP script do.

It seems like the default for throttling option in the `network` tab is set to `slow 3G`, and the page loads completely in `5.74s` while disabling cache.

If caching is enabled, it takes `2.5s` on the same slow 3G option, but once I make it on the option `no-throttling` with disabled cache the load time becomes much faster like `480ms`.

So, is performance testing relying on the worst-case or on the normal case (`fast 3G` caching enabled), and what is the ideal load time for the worst-case scenario (i.e. `slow 3G` with caching disabled).

I've searched about these options and what is the one that I should go with, I know that caching should be enabled, but I don't know if this applies when it comes to performance testing.

**Note**:
The project is running on localhost with XAMPP